# How do I allow Windows users log into my Ubuntu server

Tags: permissions, login, domain, ubuntu-server

I am new to Linux. I have the server setup (Ubuntu Server 10.04), and a windows domain server with active directory. I would like to allow a certain user groups acccess to the Ubuntu server.

Any ideas where I begin? I checked out samba, but that looks for file / printer sharing, which I don't need.

Comment: what kind of access? file shares? ssh?

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-add-ubuntu-804-to-win-server-2003-active-directory-domain.html seems to have done the trick, just trying now to restrict access only to certain groups.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so people know that the question is solved.

Comment: Thanks, last time I tried it said I did not have enough rep. Looks to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-add-ubuntu-804-to-win-server-2003-active-directory-domain.html

seems to have done the trick, just trying now to restrict access only to certain groups.